# HashSet changes its values after adding to object

Tags: java, hashset

I am trying to add to *ArrayList* objects which constructor has 3 parameters (int,int,hashset). When I add a new object, values in the hashset changes somehow, so I adding wrong values. For example I create 3 objects adding these 3 sets of Integers:

```
142082 74016 122517 57432 97112  
142082 150224 112373 129671 57432 97112 138427 115659 102283 147774  
142082 31491 129671 855 57432 73545 123160 124682 147774 61966 58590
```

But object recieves these ones:

```
70213 131022 118104 137949 4003 13798 23598 129525  
70213 131022 118104 137949 4003 13798 23598 129525  
70213 131022 118104 137949 4003 13798 23598 129525
```

I can't understand why sets change its values. This is the function code:

```
//Array of ParagData objects
public static ArrayList<ParagData> getAllParagsDatas(String indexed_data_tab) throws SQLException{
    ArrayList<IndexedItem> allIndexedItems = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<ParagData> allParags = new ArrayList<>();
    HashSet<Integer> wordsId = new HashSet<>();
    //Array of all indexed words
    allIndexedItems = GuiFindFrags.myConnection.getAllIndexedItems(indexed_data_tab);

    int curCycledParag = 1; //current paragraph num
    int curCycledTextId = 1; //current text id

    for(int i = 0; i < allIndexedItems.size(); i++){
        if((allIndexedItems.get(i).textId == curCycledTextId) && allIndexedItems.get(i).paragNum == curCycledParag){
            if(allIndexedItems.get(i).wordId != 0) wordsId.add(allIndexedItems.get(i).wordId);
        }
        else {          
            allParags.add(new ParagData(allIndexedItems.get(i).textId, allIndexedItems.get(i).paragNum, wordsId));
            wordsId.clear();
            curCycledParag = allIndexedItems.get(i).paragNum;
            curCycledTextId = allIndexedItems.get(i).textId;
        }
    } 
    return allParags;
}
```

In this code I:

```
allIndexedItems = GuiFindFrags.myConnection.getAllIndexedItems(indexed_data_tab);
```

1. get the ArrayList allIndexedItems of objects, describing the words in the texts (texts are in the mysql table). This object has these parameters:

   - int text_id (in which text the word was found)
   - int parag_num (in which paragraph of the text it was found)
   - int word id - (id of word in the dictionary which is in mysql table too)

   There are other paramenters in the constructor of this object but they are not used here. 
   So this ArrayList describes all the words in all the texts.
2. ```
   int curCycledParag = 1; //current paragraph num
   int curCycledTextId = 1; //current text id
   ```

Create variables for current text and current paragraph. They will be changed during the cycle.

3. Also at the begininng I created `HashSet<Integer> wordsId` - in this HashSet all the word_id of *one* paragraph of text should be added. 
   So I start cycle of adding the `word_ids` to the `HashSet` while `text_id` of each word (`allIndexedItems.get(i).textId`) = current text (variable `curCycledTextId`) and word paragraph (`allIndexedItems.get(i).paragNum`) = value of variable `curCycledParag`.

   SO: when all the words of paragraph are added to the HashSet I have to create another object, describing paragraph - object ParagData (it has:

   - int text_id (id of the texts where this paragraph is located)
   - int parag_num (number of paragraph in the text)
   - HashSet wordIdsSet - (all the word ids of paragraph)

   And also at the beginning I created an `ArrayList<ParagData> allParags` for adding all the paragraph objects. The function return this arrayList. 
   So when all the paragraph words are added to HashSet I create a new object ParagData and add it to ArrayList allParags. After that I clean the HashSet and use it aging for adding word ids of next paragraph.

   ```
   else {              
       allParags.add(new ParagData(allIndexedItems.get(i).textId, allIndexedItems.get(i).paragNum, wordsId));
       wordsId.clear();
       curCycledParag = allIndexedItems.get(i).paragNum;
       curCycledTextId = allIndexedItems.get(i).textId;
   }
   return allParags;
   ```

When I add new ParagData object to ArrayList its values changes - so not corrent values become added to allParags ArrayList

Comment: Could you please give more info on what you doing in code and also refine your input to much readable form, Its not that easy to make something out of it

Comment: You're adding references to the same `HashSet` object to each of your `ParagData` instances. Create a `new HashSet` for each one.

Comment: khelwood, before each cycle of adding data in the HashSet I clear it. And after that I use it again - wordsId.clear();

Comment: Can you please give the code without your user defined object? so we can easily understand.

Comment: @nrvmodi, I added the description of the code. Sorry, I don't know how I can make code more readable

Comment: @AlexeyRumin Yes, this is what khelwood meant. This behaviour is wrong if you don't copy the content of that hashset in the `ParagData` constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new Hashset object for each ParagDat. The Hashset is not immutable after created. What you area dealing with is the same object.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Now it works well. But it is still strange for me - why I can't use the same hashSet link just using clear when I want to use it again...

Comment: @Alexey Rumin, if you try to clear the current wordsId(hashset), the reference of wordsId(hashset) you've already warpped in the ParagDat objects will be cleared as well. You need to clone the old one or create a new one for processing.

Comment: Thank you a lot for explanation!